# Powershell How to register an event on network connection lost?

Tags: powershell, wmi

Any idea how to register PowerShell event on disconnect network?
Something like

```
on_disconnet network {
    raise an event
    notify system
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I  am looking for a notification when network cable is unplugged or wifi got disconnected

Comment: Notification for a user (as in "a popup") or for an automation mechanism (as in "something that triggers some program or script")?

Comment: if network connection lost  i need to start another application.that's my requirement

Comment: You can adapt [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Check-Network-0f7a4e91) for your use-case.

Comment: @Jelphy thankyou for your reply ,This script is doing one time checking for internet connection, i am looking for an event.

Comment: @jack I'm not sure I follow. You could adapt the script to loop & check for a connection, if the connection drops write to Windows event log?

Comment: yes @Jelphy! am also thinking about that, i will try create an event if nothing works ill loop and check the status

Comment: @jack OK. Edit your question with the adapted code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
Function Test-ForNetwork1

{
Write-Host " connected"
}
Function Test-ForNetwork2

{
Write-Host "dis connected"
}

Register-WMIEvent -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSNdis_StatusMediaConnect -Action {Test-ForNetwork1} 

Register-WMIEvent -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSNdis_StatusMediaDisconnect -Action {Test-ForNetwork2}
```